# How to append data when fetching a second time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble with appending my data when I call my fetch method a second time. On the initial render, my component fetches data from my database and stores it in my followingData state. Then, when I scroll to the bottom, I call my fetchData function again, but instead of my new data being appended in to the followingData state, it replaces it, and now only the new data is displayed on the my screen.

Here is the code:

```
function Following({route, navigation}) {
  const [followingData, setfollowingData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState();

  const fetchData = () => {
    const dataaRef = firestore().collection('usernames');
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    dataRef
      .doc(route.params.username.toLowerCase())
      .collection('Following')
      .onSnapshot(() => {
        dataaRef
          .doc(route.params.username.toLowerCase())
          .collection('Following')
          .orderBy('followedAt')
          .startAfter(lastVisible || 0)
          .limit(7)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.empty
              ? null
              : setLastVisible(
                  snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1].data().followedAt,
                );
            let promises = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data();
              promises.push(
                data.path.get().then((res) => {
                  const userData = res.data();
                  return {
                    profileName: doc.id ? doc.id : null,
                    displayName: userData.displayName
                      ? userData.displayName
                      : null,
                    followerCount:
                      userData.followers !== undefined ? userData.followers : 0,
                    followingCount:
                      userData.following !== undefined ? userData.following : 0,
                    imageUrl: userData.imageUrl ? userData.imageUrl : null,
                  };
                }),
              );
            });
            Promise.all(promises).then((res) => {
              setfollowingData(res);
            });
            setLoading(false);
          });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    const cleanup = fetchData();

    return cleanup;
  }, [route.params.username]);

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={styles}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" color="#222" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{left: width * 0.05}}>Following</Text>
      </View>

      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <FolloweringScreens
            data={followingData}
            screen={'Following'}
            username={route.params.username}
            navigation={navigation}
            fetchData={fetchData}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Following;
```

The child component looks like this, where the fetchData is being called upon when scrolling to the end:

```
function FolloweringScreens({
  data,
  screen,
  username,
  navigation,
  fetchData,
  setNext,
}) {

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        onEndReached={fetchData} <<-- CALLING FETCHDATA AGAIN TO GET MORE DATA
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
                  (I use my data here)
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default FolloweringScreens;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append the new data, then it is better if you use a [callback function](https://reactgo.com/react-setstate-callback/#using-the-setstate-callback-in-hooks) in your *setState*:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
  setfollowingData(oldState => ({...oldState, ...res}));
});
```

Here you take all the values from the old state, put it in a new object and add the new data to it. If your state is an array, you would have to exchange the **{}** with **[]**:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
  setfollowingData(oldState => ([...oldState, ...res]));
});
```

**UPDATE:** Added Example

Comment: This returns data like this : {"0": {First set of data}, "1": {second set of data}, "2": {second set of data}, "3": {second set of data}, "4": {second set of data}} but I need the data in an array so i can use it in the flatlLst.

Comment: That is why you should exchange the curly braces for the array ones. I will update my answer.

Comment: When i try this, i get an error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: The response i get when fetching the data is an array of objects

Comment: Are you sure that it is an array of objects? The error message sounds like it is something else. Can you console log the response and add it to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have updated my question to explain more on the issue. I am really struggling so any help would be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Ok, but you always receive an array back, so the error message makes no sense in this case. In order to fix your problem of that the function fires to fast, you could build a debounce function: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Comment: I am such an idiot. So the reason I was receiving this error is because the initial state was empty. After changing the initial state to [], it now works. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you so much for your help, Appreciate it, Thank you sir!!!